# Set pulseaudio sample rate for a single source

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, microphone

I have a Logitech C310 webcam, which pulseaudio believes has a sample rate of 48 kHz. However, the hardware only works at 16 kHz. Most applications will try to use the 16 Khz audio at 48 kHz, resulting in a high-pitched squirrel or chipmunk sound.

This happens across a range of applications, and in Windows as well. How do I force pulseaudio to use the source at a 16 kHz sample rate?

Comment: First step is to check if the problem already appears on the ALSA level, because Pulseaudio trusts the ALSA data. Test with `arecord -f ...` and `arecord --dump-hw-params ...` after stopping Pulseaudio (or use `pasuspender`). If it's on the ALSA level, I'd try to fix it in `~/.asoundrc` via a plugin, and then make Pulseaudio use that plugin instead of the raw hardware device.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks, that gave me a starting point. I was able to reproduce the behavior with `pasuspender` & `arecord`. I was also getting weird behavior where `arecord` would freeze indefinitely and not record audio. Eventually gave up and bought a replacement.

Comment: Similar problem https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/500772/111181

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same answer, for the same camera. I found it in the pulse-cli-syntax manpage. I had to add a line to my /etc/pulse/default.pa

```
update-source-proplist alsa_input.usb-046d_081b_FD644020-02.analog-mono format=s16le rate=16000
```

Edit, didn't work. The only thing I can think of is turning off udev and loading modules manually