# Setting different per-device sampling rates in pulseaudio?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

#### My Audio Devices

- Input: Logitech C310 webcam mic (16kHz)
- Output: Sony MBH20 Bluetooth headset (44.1kHz) in High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) mode

#### My Problem

With the default PulseAudio settings, the bluetooth headset sounds excellent,
but recordings over the webcam mic are high-pitched and sped up, like an Alvin
and the Chipmunks recording.

If I configure PulseAudio to set the sampling rate to 16kHz,

```
# /etc/pulse/daemon.conf

default-sample-rate = 16000
```

then the webcam works perfectly, but the sound quality through the headset is
severely degraded.

#### My questions

- Is there any way to configure the sampling rate for only a single source?
- `pacmd list-sources` erroneously reports the sampling rate of the webcam mic
  as 48kHz (`sample spec: s16le 1ch 48000Hz`). Could that be the problem? If
  so, is there any way to manually change the sample spec? If not, does this
  qualify as a bug that should be reported to the pulseaudio maintainers?
- or is there another fix to this problem that I’m not seeing?

Comment: Which version of Pulseaudio you are using?

Comment: Have you tried different resample-method?

Comment: Similar [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/388127/111181)

Comment: I'm on pulseaudio 12.2, but at this point, I've just switched to another mic, so I may never get around to fully debugging this issue!

Comment: Here is a bug report for this: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/980

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting

```
   default-sample-rate = 44100
   alternate-sample-rate = 16000
```

and/or

```
   avoid-resampling = yes
```

if you have pulseaudio version >= 11.

In Pulseaudio 13 there may be even more options, see [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/commit/ef094638f552a9cd8006a3f31da7d2c649104d5f)

I think it is good to make a bug report about this issue and link it in a comment.

Comment: Still, I think the resampling should produce good quality sound even when using 48000 Hz sample rate. You could try to improve resamping by setting `resample-method = speex-float-5` in daemon.conf; see ` man pulse-daemon.conf `

Comment: I'm having the same problem as the OP. The problem is not with resampling, but with the fact that some webcam's don't report their sample rates. So `pacmd list-sources` will always show the value of `default-sample-rate` as the sample rate of that device, and the necessary resampling never takes place, regardless of the selected algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The native sound card word rate should match the default-sample-rate otherwise there will be band limitation as observed.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem (high-pitched sound from camera mic) with Logitech Webcam 9000.
After reading many discussions on Stackexchange, [ALSA manual](https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Asoundrc#Aliases), [ALSA alternative manual](https://alsa.opensrc.org/), [ALSA guide](https://www.volkerschatz.com/noise/alsa.html)  I got solution.

Find My camera ALSA name (U0x46d0x809) or index (2)

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                      HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfce60000 irq 73
 1 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xfcb00000 irq 75
 2 [U0x46d0x809    ]: USB-Audio - USB Device 0x46d:0x809
                      USB Device 0x46d:0x809 at usb-0000:2d:00.3-3, high speed
```

Create config for ALSA  ~/.asoundrc

```
      pcm.usb
      {
          type hw
          card U0x46d0x809
      }

      pcm.!default
      {
          type asym
          capture.pcm
          {
              type plug
              slave.pcm "usb"
              rate 16000
          }
      }
```

I still not make long real life tests (skype, obs, etc...) but recording in audacity and test calls in skype sounds good.

I still not completely understand ALSA configs

**UPD: It not helps.** Now look like first Skype call after reboot pitched, next normal. (need checking)

Answer (score -1):

It seems I did not find this post before I have published my own.

I see that you found no solution yet (many years later) because no one answer is marked.

I tried to record via my webcam setting sample format 16le (with no changes of rate) and I got perfect result.

If you found a solution, please wrote it on this post :) and I will delete my post then.

My post is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/723831/changing-sample-format-for-usb-microphone)